# Not being able to fetch csv with class method

Tags: php, oop, php-5.3

I'm having a headache trying to figure this out.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
index.php
helpers:
  API.php
  helpers.php
assets:
  products.csv
debug:
  debug_info.txt
```

My index file looks as follows:

```
<?php
require_once 'helpers/API.php';
file_put_contents('debug/debug_info.txt', "New request started");
if (in_array($_GET['action'],array('insertOrder','updateOrder'))){
    $date = date(DATE_RFC2822);
    $api = new API();
    file_put_contents('debug/debug_info.txt', "New: {$_GET['action']} at {$date}\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    file_put_contents('debug/debug_info.txt', "This is the product " . $api->getOrder());
}
```

**API.php**

```
<?php

class API {
    private $order;
    private $product_table;

    function __construct(){
        $this->order = $this->setOrder();
        $this->product_table = $this->setProductTable();
    }

    public function setOrder(){return $this->readJSON();}
    public function setProductTable(){return $this->readProductsCSV(__DIR__ . '/../assets/products.csv');}

    public function getOrder(){return $this->order;}
    public function getProductsTable(){return $this->product_table;}

    private function readJSON(){
       $stream = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
       $json = stream_get_contents($stream);
       fclose($stream);
       return print_r(json_decode($json, true), true);
    }

    private function readProductsCSV($csv = '', $delimiter = ','){
        if (!file_exists($csv) || !is_readable($csv)){
            return "Someone f*cked up -_-";
        }

        $header = NULL;
        $data = array();

        if (($handle = fopen($csv, 'r')) !== false){
            while (($row = fgetcsv($csv, 100, $delimiter)) !== false){
                    if (!$header)
                        $header = $row;

                    else if($row[0] != ''){
                        $row = array_merge(array_slice($row,0,2), array_filter(array_slice($row, 2)));
                        $sku = $row[0];
                        $data[$sku]['productCode'] = $row[1];
                        $data[$sku]['Description'] = $row[2];
                    }
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
        array_change_key_case($data, CASE_LOWER);
        return print_r($data, true);
    }
}
```

When I use `file_put_contents('debug/debug_info.txt', $api->getOrder());` I get the data correctly ( I have to comment all the product_table parts for it to work tho ).

But I can't get the CSV file no matter what I do.
I've ran `file_exists() && is_readable` ( and they passed ) but still nothing.

If I declare the function readProductsCSV in the `index.php` it works.. but it seems using it as a method bugs everything.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic bugs:

```
    if (($handle = fopen($csv, 'r')) !== false){
            ^---your csv file handle

        while (($row = fgetcsv($csv, 100, $delimiter)) !== false){
                                ^---your csv filename, which SHOULD be the handle
```

Since you're trying to use a string as a filehandle, you get a boolean `false` back from `fgetcsv()` for failure, that false terminates the `while` loop, and `$data` stays an empty array.

Comment: Nice catch! Much thanks, m8! I also had to change the `return` in `public function setProductTable()` from `return $this->readProductsCSV(__DIR__ . '/../assets/products.csv')` to `return $this->readProductsCSV($csv = __DIR__ . '/../assets/products.csv')`